# single-character full text search not working (Laravel)?

Tags: mysql, laravel, full-text-search

When I'm going to search by name call `Headstone` It will give the search result, But when I going to search by name call `stone` the half of word, no result found.

This is my code to search :

```php
Locations::orWhereRaw('MATCH (headstone_memorial_details) AGAINST (?)', array(['+' . 'Headstone' . ' *']));
```

I'm using `Laravel 5.7`

How to fixed this Problem? I want to search(full-text search) records by single character of word.

Answer (score 2):

Change your query to:

```
Locations::where('headstone_memorial_details', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();
```

Don't forget to replace the `$search` variable with the variable that holds the data that you are searching for.